# Is there Any way to use one Function in All activity of android

Tags: java, android, oop, methods

I have About 15-20 Activity which uses the same function again and again
I want to know is there any way to write that function once and call it again and again.

As writing the same piece of code again and again is going to be tough task
and it will be very difficult if I have to change anything.

The function doesn't require any parameters, it's a simple function, which has no relation with current Activity.

Comment: Yes, you can declare the function as public static , and then use the function in any activity

Comment: Create that function as a static function, static functions can be called directly from any activity.

Comment: To call that function just prefix the function name with the "ActivityName."

Comment: There are so many ways to do this, but they are covered in any basic programming introduction

Answer (score 0):

> Is there Any way to use one Function in All activity of android

Yes you can use one function in all activity

Try this

```
public class Utils {
    public static void myMethod(){

    }
}
```

than use like this way to call your method

```
Utils.myMethod();
```

Comment: Methods in Java should always start with lowercase letter according to Oracle conventions.

Comment: @user8 Thanks for your value able comment.

Answer (score -1):

Yes , you can create one utility class and paste that function into that , make it **static** , then you can access that function using that class name

```
public class Utility{

      public static methodName() {
        // your logic
    }

}
```

then call it using `Utility.methodName()`